# The fastest disk search possible

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, search, file-management, search-indexing

I currently have windows indexing service and no other disk search/indexing program installed.

**I want the indexing software to load the entire index database into RAM**

- Is there any way to make windows indexing service to load the whole index
  database and just search files in the index in memory?
- If not, is there a workaround, like telling superfetch to cache the index database file? (probably impossible)

> Moving the index database to a ramdrive is not a valid option.
>
> Buying an ssd is not a valid option.
>
> I am open for software recommendations.
>
> Free software is priority.
>
> It's ok if the software uses the entire RAM

Disks to be indexed

HDD1: 500gb 7200rpm sata 3

HDD2: 750gb 5200rpm usb 2.0

RAM: 4gb 533 mhz

Comment: The problem with telling Superfetch to preload the data is that Superfetch constantly re-computes what to "fetch", and I'm not aware of good ways to override it. The problem with a RAM drive is not only that data is lost on unclean shutdown but a fixed-size RAM drive is unsuited to handle file that is not of fixed size, and that it makes said RAM permanently inaccessible to applications. All that's needed is to use the Windows' standard disk cache.

Answer (score 1):

A program that used to work in a Superfetch style was [eBoostr](http://www.eboostr.com/).

I have not used it in quite some time but it works a lot like Superfetch in that it precaches program data, you could also specify what programs and data got cached into ram.

It could work using system RAM, SSDs, other hard drives and even USB  memory sticks but it sounds like you'd want the RAM only option. The amount of memory it uses is also configurable if I remember rightly.

From their website:

> Have a program you want to work faster but don't use often? Not a problem. With eBoostr's easy to use interface you can pick and choose and prioritize what programs you want eBoostr to accelerate.

Sounds a lot like what you are after.